# HttpContext is null in Angular2 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, session

I need to persist the state of a particular object from a different library in my Controller, but I've followed some tutos that teach how to use `Session` in `HttpContext`, but `HttpContext` is null in a controller's constructor

Middleware is all set up:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddDbContext<AutoListDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //(...)

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        //(...)
     }
```

And I'm trying the simplest thing possible in this scenario:

```
    public AddDoorController(AutoListDbContext context)
    {
        var building = new Building(context);
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("building", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(building));
    }
```

But `HttpContext` (inherited from `BaseController`) is null. What am I missing?